# C++ reading file into an object

Tags: c++

So I'm trying trying read a file into several objects, and right now I'm practicing by trying to insert a single line into a single object. This the object class I'm trying to insert the file in:

```
Cust(string name, bool robber, int time, int items)
{
    m_name = name;
    m_robber = robber;
    m_time = time;
    m_items = items;
}
```

After reading the file, I try to insert them into the object and print the object to see if it successfully came out. I know the print function works just fine, so there's no reason to worry about that.

```
ifstream my_ifile(argv[3]);

string k_name;
bool k_robber;
int k_time;
int k_items;

my_ifile >> k_name;
my_ifile >> k_robber;
my_ifile >> k_time;
my_ifile >> k_items;

Cust k_customer(k_name, k_robber, k_time, k_items);
k_customer.print(cout);
```

The file I'm putting in has one line.

```
Robbie true 1 2
```

And the print function should print "Robbie robber 1 2". Instead this is the output I get:

```
 shopper 638496768 32631
```

It starts with a space, it's set to shopper instead of robber, the numbers are incorrect, the name is omitted entirely and the file's contents are erased. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Also how would I read through two or more lines? I.e.

```
Robbie true 1 2
Shaun false 3 4
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `my_ifile >> k_name;` reads string till first space. I suppose starting from this point you get further incorrect values.

Comment: The [`std::boolalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) [manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) might be handy to use.

Comment: I also recommend you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you, for example, step through the code to read the input line by line in a debugger, are the values you read correct?

Comment: Oh and a big thing: Did the file open okay? Do you *check* it? And do you check that `argc > 3`? If not then `argv[3]` is invalid.

Comment: Or instead of `true` and `false` in the file, use 0 and 1

Comment: I do check to make sure the file can be opened and that works fine, so I'm not worried about that. I did test with k_name, when I cout it, it just comes out blank but I'm not understanding why.